# Conditional template property binding in Angluar

Tags: angular

Is it possible to conditionally bind a property in a Angular template

For example, I got a Observable with some data

```
<my-component *ngIf="input$ | async as input"
              [input1]="input.input1"
              [overrideValue]="input.overrideValue"> <--For this value, only bind when value is not null
</my-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

You could try using safe navigation operator [?.](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator). It checks if the property is defined before accessing it.

```html
<my-component *ngIf="input$ | async as input"
              [input1]="input.input1"
              [overrideValue]="input?.overrideValue"> <--For this value, only bind when value is not null
</my-component>
```

**Option 2**

You could also try to use ternary operator.

```html
<my-component *ngIf="input$ | async as input"
              [input1]="input.input1"
              [overrideValue]="input.overrideValue ? input.overrideValue : ''"> <--For this value, only bind when value is not null
</my-component>
```

However it will bind empty string `''` if the property `overrideValue` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if there isn't a value, still that input accepts a empty string. This is something I'm trying to avoid. I can add a check in the setter of overrideValue, but I'm still looking for a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[attr.overrideValue]="input.overrideValue"

Comment: Humm, what if this is a input instead of attr?

Answer (score 0):

For the case of radio buttons with the checked property, this code works

```
<mat-radio-button 
  class="import-radio-button"
  *ngFor="let option of data.options"
  [value]="option.value"
  [checked]="option.selected ? true : null">
  {{ option.label }}
</mat-radio-button>
```